# Error al eliminar dependencia de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando quite una dependencia de `composer.json` y ejecute `composer update` se elimino el packete `caffeinated/shinobi` el cual pesaba reemplazar por otro similar ya que ese me dio muchos problemas.

Pero ahora al momento de ejecutar `composer dumpautolad` me sale un error de:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Caffeinated\Shinobi\ShinobiServiceProvider' not found

Ya borre el componente de *providers* del archivo **config/app.php** y ademas busque toda llamada de dicho componente en mis controladores y modelos y todo donde lo llame.

Ya ejecute comandos como `php artisan config:cache` y `cache:clear` y cualquier comando que ejecuto me sigue votando el error:

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Caffeinated\Shinobi\ShinobiServiceProvider' not found

Este es mi provider:

```
 'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    
    jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\RolesServiceProvider::class,
    /*
    * Package Laravel Collective
    */
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
    Backup\BackupServiceProvider::class,

],
```

Ahora no funciona nada de mi proyecto, alguien sabe que debo de hacer para que se borre definitivamente dicho componente?

Comment: Has intentado borrar lo que esta en bootstrap/cache

Comment: no, no lo intente, elimino toda la Carpeta?

Comment: los archivos packages y services

Comment: @HammerffallBK, me salvaste el proyecto, mil gracias, puedes escribirlo como respuesta para poder marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trata eliminando las archivos `packages.php` y `services.php` dentro del directorio `bootstrap/cache`.